# Reading /proc/pid/mem file returns nothing

Tags: c, linux, file, proc

I want to catch the memory mapping of current process to a file by reading the content of `/proc/pid/mem` and writing it to another file. But the resulting file is empty every time. I use `sudo`, so I have no permission errors. When I change the input file to some testing file, like `"test_file_1.txt"`, all works as expected. What I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    char filename[100];

    pid_t pid = getpid();
    printf("pid: %i\n", pid);

////It works with an usual file
//  FILE *in_file = fopen("test_file_1.txt", "r");

////But doesn't work with this:
    sprintf(filename, "/proc/%i/mem", pid);
    FILE *in_file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!in_file){
        puts("in_file can't be opened");
    }

    sprintf(filename, "mem_%i.txt", pid);
    FILE *out_file = fopen(filename, "w");
    if(!out_file){
        puts("out_file can't be opened");
    }

    char line[500];
    while(fgets(line, 500, in_file)) {
        fputs(line, out_file);             
    }

    fclose(in_file);
    fclose(out_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. This is not a text file so you can't read it line by line. 2. Please check for errors. You will get `EIO` if you try to read any part of the memory space that is not mapped. 3. To see which addresses you *can* read from, check out `/proc/$PID/maps`, seek to that location, then read

Comment: @thatotherguy I was needed `/proc/$PID/maps`, thanks.

Comment: OT: regarding: `puts("in_file can't be opened");`  1) error messages are to be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  and when the error is from a C library function should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest calling `perror( "your error message");` as `perror()` is made for that purpose.  2) This is an unrecoverable error, so the program should exit, NOT continue to execute code as if the call to `fopen()` were sucessful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/proc/PID/mem` gives access to the memory of the process as it is mapped in the process: accessing the *N*th byte of this file is equivalent to accessing `(*unsigned char)N` inside the process in C, or `ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, PID, (void*)N, NULL)` from another process (or `PTRACE_POKEDATA` for writing, and with the difference that `ptrace` accesses one word at a time, not one byte at a time).

Processes usually have nothing mapped at address 0. When you open the file and start reading, you're reading from address 0. Since there's nothing there, the `read` call returns `EIO`. Use `perror` to get more information about the failure of `fgets`.

Note that `fgets` won't let you read from `/proc/PID/mem` because it contains binary data, but `fgets` only works on text (strings that don't contain null bytes). Use `open`, `lseek` and `read` to read from `/proc/PID/mem`.

Before reading from `/proc/PID/mem`, you need to figure out where the process has things mapped. This information is in [`/proc/PID/maps`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html#process-specific-subdirectories). This file is in a text file with reasonable line lengths, so using `fopen` and `fgets` is fine.

If you're accessing the process's own memory, you can use `/proc/self/…` instead of interpolating the PID.

```
FILE *maps_file = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
if (maps_file == NULL) {perror("/proc/self/maps"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
char line[500];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), maps_file)) { ... }
fclose(maps_file);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `proc/<pid>/mem`, you should use [`process_vm_readv(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/process_vm_readv.2.html).

Really.

`/proc/<pid>/mem` is a legacy interface, which is still cute to use with `dd` from the shell ("everything is a file", etc), but it makes no point to bother with it from C.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at `/proc/pid/maps` to see if that file has the memory mapping info you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, it works. I am messing up `mem` and `maps` from time to time, but when I look it manually I try `mem`, get an error, then try `maps`, while in code I have forgotten about this... :)